# How to make a mobile menu fixed while allowing to scroll down inside it?

Tags: css

I need my mobile menu to feel the entire screen, but it doesn't fit vertically in one screen so vertical scroll must be allowed.

How to achieve that?

https://jsfiddle.net/xj5k6mfn/

HTML:

```
<div class="mobile-menu">
  <ul>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
    <li>item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.mobile-menu {
  position: fixed;
  li {
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this.. you should add any custom scroll bar

**css**

```
.mobile-menu {
  position: fixed;
  height:100vh;
  overflow:auto;
  li {
    margin-bottom: 5rem;
    padding-right:50px;
  }  
}
```